# What Are the Maximum Number of Base-10 Digits in the Integral Part of a Floating Point Number

Tags: c++, floating-point, max, decimal, numeric-limits

I want to know if there is something in the standard, like a `#define` or something in `numeric_limits` which would tell me the maximum number of base-10 digits in the integral part of a floating point type.

For example, if I have some floating point type the largest value of which is: 1234.567. I'd like something defined in the standard that would tell me 4 for that type.

Is there an option to me doing this?

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto integral_digits10 = static_cast<int>(log10(numeric_limits<T>::max())) + 1;
```

Comment: Isn't this [`std::numeric_limits::digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10)?

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think so: http://ideone.com/bocQEP unless a `double` can only contain integral types of up to 999,999,999,999,999 which seems very small for a `double`.

Comment: I do not think your calculation is right.  a `double` cannot hold a number with 309 digits in front of the decimal place.  At most it can have 15 non-decimal digits.  After that you lose precision.

Comment: Its not that it can only hold `999,999,999,999,999`.  It is just that it can only hold 15 no decimal digits before the decimal point.

Comment: @NathanOliver The calculation is right for the constant that the text of the question describes, and that calculation helps make the question unambiguous. Taking binary64 as an example of floating-point type, the largest finite value is 179769…<approx. 300 zeroes> and the OP would like to see a constant like 309 for this floating-point type.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/SUhgxb

Comment: @NathanOliver My apologies for an overbearing variable name in my example. I have learned a lot from your explanations and my unkindness did not properly express my gratitude. I'm going to replace my out of line response by saying that `numeric_limits<double>::max()` is [much bigger than 15 digits](http://ideone.com/uDqio9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value that you are looking for is [`max_exponent10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_exponent10) which:

> Is the largest positive number n such that 10<sup>n</sup> is a representable finite value of the floating-point type

Because of this relationship:

log<sub>10</sub>*x* = *n*
10<sup>*n*</sup> = *x*

Your calculation is doing, is finding *n* the way the first equation works:

```
log10(numeric_limits<T>::max())
```

The definition of `max_exponent10` is explaining that it is using a 10<sup>*n* + 1</sup> would be larger than `numeric_limits<T>::max()` but 10<sup>*n*</sup> is less than or equal to `numeric_limits<T>::max()`. **So `numeric_limits<T>::max_exponent10` is what you're looking for.**

Note that you will still need the `+ 1` as in your example, to account for the 1's place. (Because log<sub>10</sub>1 = 0) So your the number of 10-based digits required to represent `numeric_limits<T>::max()` will be:

```
numeric_limits<T>::max_exponent10 + 1
```

If you feel like validating that by hand you can check here:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/443e4d434cbcb2f6

Answer (score 2):

As Nathan Oliver points out in the comments, C++ provides [`std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10).

> the number of base-10 digits that can be represented by the type `T` without change, that is, any number with this many decimal digits can be converted to a value of type `T` and back to decimal form, without change due to rounding or overflow. For base-[`radix`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/radix) types, it is the value of [`digits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits) (`digits`-1 for floating-point types) multiplied by *log*<sub>10</sub>(`radix`) and rounded down.

The explanation for this is [explained by Rick Regan here](http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/). In summary, if your binary floating point format can store *b* bits in the significand, then you are guaranteed to be able to round-trip up to *d* decimal digits, where *d* is the largest integer such that

10<sup>*d*</sup> < 2<sup>*b*-1</sup>

In the case of an [IEEE754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (the standard `double` in C++ on most systems nowadays), then *b* = 53, and 2<sup>*b*-1</sup> = 4,503,599,627,370,496, so the format is only guaranteed to be able to represent *d* = 15 digits.

However this result holds for *all* digits, whereas you just ask about the integral part. However we can easily find a counterexample by choosing *x* = 2<sup>*b*</sup>+1, which is the smallest integer not representable by the format: for binary64 this is 9,007,199,254,740,993, which also happens to have 16 digits, and so [will need to be rounded](http://ideone.com/SUhgxb).

Comment: This answer is wrong, I'm not looking for the number that can be represented without change. I'm looking for the number of base-10 digits in the maximum value of `T`: http://ideone.com/uDqio9 In any case `numeric_limits<T>::max_exponent10` is the value I'm looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39793154/2642059

Comment: It's about 300. For all practical purposes it's a useless number to calculate as precision is nowhere near 300 digits (and what sort of instrument would make such a measurement?), and everyone represents such big numbers in scientific notation.