# What Are the Maximum Number of Base-10 Digits in the Fractional Part of a Floating Point Number

Tags: c++, floating-point, max, decimal, numeric-limits

If the a floating point number could be outputted so that there was no truncation of value (say with `setpercision`) and the number was outputted in fixed notation (say with `fixed`) what is the buffer size that would be required to guarantee the entire fractional part of the floating point number could be stored in the buffer?

I'm hoping there is something in the standard, like a `#define` or something in `numeric_limits` which would tell me the maximum base-10 value place of the fractional part of a floating point type.

I asked about the maximum number of base-10 digits in the fractional part of a floating point type here: [What Are the Maximum Number of Base-10 Digits in the Integral Part of a Floating Point Number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39776532/2642059)

But I realize this may be more complex. For example, `1.0 / 3.0` is an infinitely repeating series of numbers. When I output that using `fixed` formatting I get this many places before repeating 0s:

> 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125

But I can't necessarily say that's the maximum precision, cause I don't know how many of those trailing 0s were actually represented in the floating point's fraction, and it hasn't been shifted down by a negative exponent.

I know we have [`min_exponent10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min_exponent10) is that what I should be looking to for this?

Comment: What do you mean by maximum number of base-10 digits? `2^-100` has 100 nonzero digits in base 10 and is represented precisely in `double`.

Comment: @RawN We can see from my example that it's at least 55. I'm not interested in unique representation. I'm interested in max number of characters.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 Yeah, that's what I mean, `min_exponent10` is like 125 for a `float` for example. So do we have a maximum of 125 characters?

Comment: @JonathanMee It's unclear what you are asking. What are *base-10 digits in the fractional part of a floating point type.*?

Comment: @Jonathan The `operator>>` truncates a number on some amount of digits (and outputs zeros after that), even if we did `setprecision` with some large argument. However, the number is still stored precisely. Are you talking about numbers storage or printing?

Comment: @JonathanMee On my computer `operator>>` called with `2^-100` after `setprecision(100)` prints `0.0000000000000000000000000000007888610000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. If talking only about digits, you can have as many zeros in the end as you wish.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 Wow, that's a really good question. I'm specifically concerned with how long a string would have to be to completely contain the maximum number of characters in the fractional part of a floating point. I was planning on using a `stringstream` to extract that though. Can I manipulate how the extraction operator works using `iomanip` formatters to get the complete fractional part of the floating point, or could I just use `sprintf` perhaps?

Comment: @JonathanMee With both `std::stream`s `operator>>` and `printf` function family you have no guarantee that written number will be exactly the same after reading. Moreover, such problem also happens with large integer values, which cannot be represented in integral types, but can precisely be represented in floating-point types. If you just serialize and deserialize something, consider using binary files or writing you own serializer

Comment: @Jonathan Mee: The question is whether you require the minimum number of digits required to uniquely discriminate the floating-point value in text (such that it would roundtrip without losing precision) or to cover the exact decimal value which the fraction floating-point number represents? In the latter case a floating-point format with a base with factors other than 2 or 5 might generate an infinite string. Not that such a beast exists in practice, but I don't believe the language forbids it.

Comment: The mantisse of a *double* can store 53 bits, it can therefore have pow(2,53) = 9E15 distinct values.  So there can never be more than log10(9E15) ~= 15.95 significant digits.  Wisely rounded down to 15.  Just count them off in the value you got.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 I agree that you can have tons of zeros. For example: `setprecision(numeric_limits<int>::max())` is legal. But how many of those digits are meaningful? That's the number that I'm trying to find. Is it more clear if I say it like this: "Given all possible numbers of a floating point type, in what is the smallest place value which would be required so that all numbers could be completely represented?"

Comment: @JonathanMee So, you need the maximum precision of writing functions, not the numbers representation in memory. The question is clear now, but, unfortunately, I don't know the answer

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0: I should hope that any decent standard library implementation would take care to insure correct floating-point trips (as in Dragon4 and its ilk). Whether commonly used standard library implementations are _decent_ is another matter..

Comment: @HansPassant That's how many could be uniquely represented. Which I'm not interested in. Cause obviously I can use an exponent of -16 and then I'd need at least 16 + 15 places to represent the number.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 Care to shed some light on the subject? I still don't understand what the question is. You simply can not accurately represent a floating point (double) number with more than 15 decimals on a 64-bit machine. If the OP thinks he can, he's wrong.

Comment: I think you want (for example for `double`), `DBL_MANT_DIG - DBL_MIN_EXP` (assuming that `FLT_RADIX` is `2`). For IEEE 754 binary64 doubles this gives a value of `1074`. And for that format, `1074` digits after the decimal point are both necessary and sufficient to be able to represent the exact value of any `double`. (`5e-324` is a case where the last nonzero significant digit is in the `10^{-1074}` place.)

Comment: @RawN I couldn't care less about accuracy. I'm asking about the lowest value place. It's easiest to talk about this using writing functions.  For example if we do `cout << fixed << x` where `x` is some floating point between 1.0 and 0.0, what is the maximum number of characters needed to represent it? That's not exactly what I'm asking if `cout` doesn't exactly represent the number (which has been suggested) but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: @JonathanMee I honestly had to ask for assistance on chat and one of the suggestions was: **In order to store any double value as a decimal representation, how large should my buffer be?** Is that your question?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Hmm... that's really promising I think, provided that `DBL_MANT_DIG` did not supply a 0 for it's least significant base-10 digit. Any change that's succinctly defined somewhere?

Comment: @JonathanMee: My interpretation of your question is: (1) An assertion / assumption: there's an integer `n` such that *every* `double` (say) is an exact integer multiple of ten to the power `-n`. (That's true for `FLT_RADIX` any of `2`, `10` and `16`.) Followed by (2) The question: what's the smallest such `n`? Is that an accurate interpretation?

Comment: @RawN I like it. Adding the specification, in base-10, and for the fractional part only, I believe that is summing up what I'm asking.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `numeric_limits::min_exponent10 + numeric_limits::digits10`, but it's possible that formula is off by 1 or 2; I don't have time right now to do a full analysis. You can test it with `numeric_limits::min` which will have the maximum number of leading zeros and the full number of digits of precision. `numeric_limits::lowest` should be even more leading zeros but only one digit of precision.

Comment: @MarkRansom I was thinking that was probably it too. I'll try to spend some time on it and see if I can mathematically guarantee something.

Comment: @RawN I've tried to roll your statement into my question for clarity. Hopefully that will limit the number of unhelpful answers about uniqueness I get.

Comment: @4386427 I'm probably just missing the significance but how do denormal numbers help me? I don't feel like that puts me any closer to a finding this buffer length.

Comment: @JonathanMee - I was wrong about denormal numbers. They don't require extra digits. sry

Comment: Don't forget to include an extra character for the sign on negative numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you consider the 32 and 64 bit IEEE 754 numbers, it can be calculated as described below.

It is all about negative powers of 2. So lets see how each exponent contribute:

```
2^-1 = 0.5         i.e. 1 digit
2^-2 = 0.25        i.e. 2 digits
2^-3 = 0.125       i.e. 3 digits
2^-4 = 0.0625      i.e. 4 digits
....
2^-N = 0.0000..    i.e. N digits
```

as the base-10 numbers always end with 5, you can see that the number of base-10 digits increase by 1 when the exponent descrease by 1. **So 2^(-N) will require N digits**

Also notice that when adding those contributions, the number of resulting digits is determined by the smallest number. So what you need to find out is the smallest exponent that can contribute.

For 32 bit IEEE 754 you have:

Smallest exponent -126

Fraction bits 23

So the smallest exponent is -126 + -23 = -149, so the smallest contribution will come from 2^-149, i.e.

> For 32 bit IEEE 754 printed in base-10 there can be 149 fractional digits

For 64 bit IEEE 754 you have:

Smallest exponent -1022

Fraction bits 52

So the smallest exponent is -1022 + -52 = -1074, so the smallest contribution will come from 2^-1074, i.e.

> For 64 bit IEEE 754 printed in base-10 there can be 1074 fractional digits

Comment: This is the right math, but this isn't standard dependent. If it was we wouldn't have to qualify "for IEEE 754" floating points only. Additionally this is working in base-2 not base-10. Which we'd need to translate to to determine base-10 buffer size.

Comment: @JonathanMee - See the calculation of `2^-1 = 0.5`, `2^-2 = 0.25` the RHS is indeed base-10. So this is the way to calculate the maximum number of digits in the fractional part when printed in base-10.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't understand that first pass. That's really powerful.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really want to know how many "digits are in the fractional part", this statement shows that you're not 100% clear on what is happening under the hood in a floating point representation. There is not a separate precision for the integer and the fractional part.

What you really want to know is the *precision of the representation*.

1) A 32-bit, single-precision IEEE754 number has 24 mantissa bits, which gives about `24 * log10(2) = 7.2` digits of precision.

2) A 64-bit, double precision IEEE754 number has 53 mantissa bits, which gives about `53 * log10(2) = 16.0` digits of precision.

Suppose you're working with double precision numbers. If you have a very small base-10 number, say between 0 and 1, then you will have about 16 decimal digits of precision after the decimal point. This is what your `1.0/3.0` example shows above- you know that the answer should be 0.3 repeating, but you have sixteen threes after the decimal point before the answer turns into nonsense.

If you have a very large number, say a billion divided by three (`1000000000.0/3.0`) then on my machine the answer will look something like this:

```
1000000000.0/3.0 = 333333333.333333313465118
```

In this case you still have about 16 digits of *precision*, but the precision is split across the integral and fractional part. There are 9 precise digits in the integral part, and 7 precise digits in the fractional part. The eight digit onwards in the fractional part is garbage.

Likewise, suppose we divide one quintillion (18 zeroes) by three. On my machine:

```
1000000000000000000.0/3.0 = 333333333333333312.000000000000000
```

You still have sixteen digits of precision, but zero of those digits are after the decimal point.

Comment: I am 100% clear on how a floating point works. I clearly am not 100% sure how to express my question cause people keep telling me about unique representation. I'm looking for a number with all 1s in the mantissa, and the most negative exponent. I care not for unique representation. If you do `cout << fixed << x` I'd like to know what is the smallest value place that will be written. It's far smaller than 18 places after the 0.

Comment: @JonathanMee Can't answer the main question, but I can answer on how to get the smallest number that's larger than 0: [`std::nextafter`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/caa340f800726256)

Comment: @JonathanMee The fixed output specifier has nothing to do with the floating point representation. It will print out as many decimal digits as are specified by the programmer in ios_base::precision - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/ - this will print out as many decimal places you ask for, regardless of whether they're garbage or not.

Comment: @JonathanMee The smallest representable denormalized number is 2^-149, which is (roughly) a decimal point followed by 44 zeroes and then a 1.

Comment: @David: I think the OP is interested in the number of digits required to express the *exact* value (not the *rough* value) of `2^{-149}` in decimal (which is also the max number of digits required for *any* IEEE 754 binary32 value). That exact value is `0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140129846432481707092372958328991613128026194187651577175706828388979108268586060148663818836212158203125`, requiring 149 decimal digits after the point.

Answer (score 2):

I'm reasonably certain the standard doesn't (and can't, without imposing other restrictions) provide a pre-defined constant to specify the number you're asking for.

Floating point is most often represented in base 2, but base 16 and base 10 are also in reasonably wide use.

In all of these cases, the only factors in the base (2 and possibly 5) are also factors of 10. As a result, we never get an infinitely repeating number when converting from them to base 10 (decimal).

The standards don't restrict floating point to such representations though. In theory, if somebody really wanted to they could use (for example) base 3 or base 7 for their floating point representation. If they did so, it would be trivial to store a number that would repeat indefinitely when converted to decimal. For example 0.1 in base 3 would represent 1/3, which repeats infinitely when converted to base 10. Although I've never heard of anybody doing it, I believe such an implementation could meet the requirements of the standard.

For a typical binary representation, `min_exponent` should probably be a reasonable proxy for the value you want. Unfortunately, it's probably not possible to state things much more precisely than that though.

For example, an implementation is allowed to store intermediate values to greater precision than it stores in memory, so it's possible that (for example) if you give `1.0/3.0` literally in your source code, the result could actually differ form the value produced by reading a pair of inputs at run time, entering 1 and 3, and dividing them. In the former case, the division might be carried out at compile time, so the result you printed out would be exactly the size of a `double`, with no extra. When you enter the two values at run time, the division would be carried out at run time, and you might get a result with higher precision.

The standard does also require that the base of the floating point be documented as `std::numeric_limits<T>::radix`. Based on this, you could compute an approximation of the maximum number of places after the decimal point based on radix<sup>min_exponent</sup>, as long as the prime factors of the radix were shared with the prime factors of 10.

Comment: So if I'm interpreting the OP's question correctly, for the *most* typical binary representation (IEEE 754), `min_exponent10` *isn't* a good proxy for the desired value, but `min_exponent` *is*. That's because it takes `min_exponent` *decimal* digits after the point to write out the full value of `2**min_exponent`. (You can convince yourself of this by looking at the first few negative powers of 2: `0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625`, etc: one extra digit is needed every time.) For IEEE 754 `binary64` format, the max number of digits after the point needed is exactly `1074`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I'm not sure if OP is asking for the maximum number of *significant* digits or the maximum number of *possible non-zero* digits, but you should expand your comment into its own answer. If it gets accepted, then we'll know.

Answer (score 2):

For 64-bit IEEE double precision, the greatest number of significant digits in an exact decimal conversion is 767.  This is the exact decimal representation of the value with the least exponent value (1) and the most fraction bits set (53).  (The largest subnormal value has the same number of significant decimal digits.)

`0x1fffffffff: 6.79038653103946484377229843314461138310092194376426254559711066591341199697795428720719286691708030861257706156230052848270284693281999335257284225503333669621306363815173250949032599895939692485035854980886484314557513280150853794570573829826804739857524570119217960803180407426491111965307363413286730767487798931547682783285587237815896874519586247523590053014866896717670220058410681569440570831708335441818365520992706048929416204456554630166566744761505361796609796460970870848607530858252375458051540998088502646723863112078256283270166032158271317445541281132771025125941275958574416739473064262902084753576460564142184397648156338301251133401530253459935315283438205175670237273725515135411912887673125670769439486684770912461317493580281734466552734375E-313`

Answer (score 0):

`std::numeric_limits<double>::min_exponent`

> Minimum negative integer value such that radix raised to (min_exponent-1) generates a normalized floating-point number.
>   Equivalent to FLT_MIN_EXP, DBL_MIN_EXP or LDBL_MIN_EXP for floating types.

`min_exponent10` also is available.

> Minimum negative integer value such that 10 raised to that power generates a normalized floating-point number.
>   Equivalent to FLT_MIN_10_EXP, DBL_MIN_10_EXP or LDBL_MIN_10_EXP for floating types.

Comment: So in other words FLT_MIN_EXP if the float format support denormals and FLT_MIN_EXP+FLT_DIG plus/minus a fudge factor if it doesn't. But can we compute the exact value portably at compile-time? Also, do we require the maximum number of digits to represent any fractional value exactly in decimal, or will the minimum uniquely identifiable rendering suffice?